# Why script delete file even with message rm: cannot remove '/path/file.txt': No such file or directory?

Tags: bash, rm

I made a bash script that delete files into a folder through a loop. The shell give me the error 
`rm: cannot remove '/path/file.txt': No such file or directory` but the script remove the files correctly. So what could produce this error?

Answer (score 2):

If the script is deleting the file but printing that error-message, then it's presumably trying to delete the file *twice* — either there's a duplicate command, or there's a duplicate argument to the `rm` command. The first time works, the second time prints the error-message.

Comment: got it. Thank you!!